# Meteor bundle fails because fibers.node is missing

Tags: meteor

The bundled node.fibers fails to load after deployment to a different server with the following error:

```
/home/ec2-user/bundle/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:13
    throw new Error('`'+ modPath+ '.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibe
          ^
Error: `/home/ec2-user/bundle/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-v8-3.11/fibers.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/bundle/server/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:13:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/bundle/server/server.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
```

Comment: In case this would be of use to you, here's an EC2 install script for Meteor: https://gist.github.com/matb33/5322002

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Node fibers have to be re-installed after unpacking the bundle. To fix this problem go to the server directory.

```
$ cd bundle/programs/server
```

Then un-install `fibers`

```
$ npm uninstall fibers
```

Then install `fibers`

```
$ npm install fibers
```

Then start your application

```
$ cd ../../
$ PORT=3000 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp node bundle/main.js
```

You will have to repeat that every time you update the app. This is just the way Meteor uses Node at the moment. Potential long-term fix can be found here: http://meteorhacks.com/how-meteor-uses-node.html

NOTE: On Meteor 0.6.5 and Node 0.10.* this may work slightly differently. You may have to remove fibers manually from `bundle/server` as well as `bundle/programs/server`. You can do that with `$ rm -R node_modules/fibers`. Then you'll have to reinstall fibers from both locations with `$ npm install fibers`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the fibers module needs to be installed INSIDE of the server folder. Everybody else missed that very important detail.

Comment: Why is it necessary to re-install fibers? None of the other node modules bundled with the server need to be re-installed? The reademe created with the bundle says that you need in INSTALL fibers, but it doesn't mention UNINSTALLING first. This appears to be an oversight.

Comment: Installing in `bundle/programs/server` as opposed to only `bundle/server`is the key to get this working.

Comment: Not working for me with Meteor 0.6.5.1 on Linux. Console just hangs when I run "node main.js". I tried an "strace", which reveals that it gets stuck on "epoll_wait(5,"

Comment: @GraemePyle I have the same problem, console hangs.

Comment: @graemepyle I upgrade meteor to 0.6.6. Fixed the issue.

Comment: for those here reading with Windows10, npm 3.6.0, node 5.8.0, meteor 1.2.1, I had to uninstall fibre in C:/users/<myuser>/node_modules... I did not have to reinstall it, either, when using `iron create my-project`, it did automatically install it correctly

Comment: Iam facing the same issue..But its running on bluemix..Can someone help me out how we can fix this

Comment: Just putting here in case there are other people having this issue. I did `npm install fibers@3` as suggested in the fibers's documentation to make it work with node 8.9.4. My npm version is `6.5.0` and the npm inside meteor is `5.6.0`. Doing `meteor npm install fibers@3` inside `bundle/programs/server` didn't work for me, but doing `npm install fibers@3` worked.

Comment: Guys, this is a global package, no need to attach it to your project.

$ rm -R node_modules/fibers and then
$ npm install fibers -g

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Meteor 1.0.3.2 and Node 0.12.0.
I had to downgrade to Node 0.10.31.
This fixed the issue.

Remember all instructions are in the readme file in the bundle folder.

Comment: really old post? nodejs.org says v4.4.0 LTS and v5.8.0 stable are latest

Answer (score 2):

### Mismatched Node Versions

The versions of node **MUST** match when you do the `npm install` and when you run the meteor app: `node app.js`.

Otherwise you can end up with different versions of expected `glibc` folders...

### To see if you have this problem:

1. note the runtime error you are seeing.  For example, in my case:

```
Try running this to fix the issue: /usr/bin/node <bundle location>/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/build
Cannot find module '<bundle location>/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-83-libc/fibers`
```

- The fix instructions referred to `/usr/bin/node` even though I was managing my node version via `nvm`.
- The executable was looking for `fibers` in the `linux-x64-83-libc` folder.

2. navigate to `bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin` & examine your `glibc` subfolders.  In my case: `linux-x64-57-glibc` & `linux-x64-64-glibc`

- My executable is looking for `linux-x64-83-libc` & it does not exist.

### Notes

In my case I was using `nvm` to manage my node versions.  But as I could see in the `fix` instructions, my executable was using `/usr/bin/node` and not the `nvm` version I was expecting.

### Fix

I removed the `/usr/bin/node` version via `sudo apt-get remove nodejs` and all was good.  Everything started using the `nvm` version.

Comment: `sudo apt-get uninstall nodejs` is not correct, use `sudo apt-get remove nodejs` instead