# meteor deploy to ubuntu fails to start

Tags: meteor

I'm running meteor on ubuntu 12 LTS with node 0.10. My meteor version is 0.6.5.1. I followed the instruction here and got to node main.js. But the console hangs, nothing happens.

Here's a similar question with comments in answer about the problem.

[Meteor bundle fails because fibers.node is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327088/meteor-bundle-fails-because-fibers-node-is-missing)

Any suggestion on how to fix this hang?

Comment: Meteor didn't migrate to node 0.10 until the 0.6.6 release. Does it still hang if you update meteor?

Comment: Yes it was the problem. Works after I upgrade to 0.6.6.