# Nginx reverse proxy + Meteor corrupt js files

Tags: nginx, proxy, meteor, meteorite

I setup'd a nginx reverse proxy (port 80) redirecting all /proposals requests to meteor/mrt server on 3000. However, the jquery.js file when accessed thru reverse proxy at( http://koinify.com/proposals/packages/jquery.js) is always cut-off around line 1400, so the meteor application doesn't load becuz of the corrupted js file. Yet, when access directly at port 3000 it seem to be just fine: http://koinify.com:3000/proposals/packages/jquery.js

Here's the nginx reverse proxy:
    upstream app2 {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

```
location ^~ /proposals {
     proxy_pass http://app2;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: Are you bundling your app?

Comment: You should, for any production app, though I don't know if that's your problem. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003689/recommended-nginx-configuration-for-meteor) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316344/meteor-vs-meteor-bundle-for-production) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065873/update-deployed-meteor-app-while-running-with-minimum-downtime-best-practice) for some relevant information.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/18003689/586086 for working nginx configurations; I use this for an un-bundled app.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: Here is the answer, and checkout my comment on it: http://serverfault.com/questions/588613/sudden-error-with-wordpress-with-nginx-only-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-en