# Meteor: issue in building. Error Cannot find module 'fibers'

Tags: meteor, fibers

We have a meteor application. It is being built using the command 
`meteor build .`
Now, I extract the tar.gz created from the above step and go till the main.js location. Now when I execute node main.js, it gives the following error:

```
\meteor\bundle>node main.js module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^ Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\megmTest5\ows-dev\meteor\meteor.tar\meteor\bundle\programs\server\boot.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

Unable to get this application running. Can someone suggest something

Comment: This gets asked a lot. Do google searches for `meteor Cannot find module fibers` and `meteor install fibers` and tell me which one worked so I can mark this as a duplicate. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327088/meteor-bundle-fails-because-fibers-node-is-missing) is popular.

Comment: already tried a few and they didn't work. Only downgrading nodejs worked which isn't really a solution.

Comment: Well that's an important clue, because meteor requires older versions of node. With meteor 1.2.1 you should be running node 0.10.40. What version did you switch to?