# throw new Error('`'+ modPath+ '.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers

Tags: node.js, npm, angular2-seed

I am developing angularseedadvanced app.

- https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced

Web and desktop app successfully created. But while running android app failed to run due to following error:

```
throw new Error(''+ modPath+ '.node is missing. Try reinstalling node-fibers
```

What should I do?

The used stack:

```
Node v7.0.0
npm 3.10.9
```

Any help will highly appreciable and helpful!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327088/meteor-bundle-fails-because-fibers-node-is-missing check this

Comment: i already referred that, but unfortunately it's not solved my issue. and i install Nativescript once again using npm install -g nativescript command and run the nativescript app using npm run start.android that solved this issue.

Comment: thats great that u solved your issue @Khushi